# How to start Kivy and start coding

Tags: kivy

I successfully installed Kivy under Ubuntu: pip install kivy[full] kivy-examples

Now, what command to use to start Kivy and get on with the coding?

There is no icon for Kivy under the startmenu Development folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kivy is a library for python, it is not a development environment. You have to use your own IDE and then you can implement kivy into your python code.